# \max with two arguments below eachother

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to use `\max` with two arguments like so:

`\max_{0 \leq k \leq n, 0 \leq l \leq n}`

But I want to have the

`0 \leq l \leq n` below the `0 \leq k \leq n`

not next to it.

How do I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code

Comment: the answer is \max_{\substack{0 \leq k \leq n \\ 0 \leq l \leq n}}

Comment: I've rolled back the edit here: the site structure deliberately keeps questions and answers separate, and in this case as a dupe the answer is to read the linked question. (Note: the model for StackExchange is that questions/answers should have value beyond just the OPs problem.)

Comment: The reason I edited is because the linked duplicate is only about using two lines of \text in a subscript. Getting from there to the solution of my specific problem was, at least for me, not entirely trivial. I was just hoping to save someone with a similar problem some time.

Comment: @VincentPfenninger You could always add a new answer there, if different enough, or make a suggested edit to the relevant answer. Or leave a comment on that answer. That way, all the relevant information will be in one place for people to find.